# Mikro-orm: How to get results from queries with aggregates into their own entity?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mikro-orm

suppose i have `User` and `Post` entities with `User` one-to-many `Post` . I want to fetch a list of users with `id`, `username`, `post_count`. The sql query for this would look like this:

```sql
select u.id, u.username, count(p.id)
from users u left join posts p on u.id = p.user_id
group by u.id
```

I want to fetch the results of this query into its own entity, like

```
class PostsCountPerUser {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  count: number
}
```

How can i do this via mikro-orm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no support for view entities, which is pretty much what you are asking for - you can subscribe here:

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/672

edit: nowadays (v5) there are also [virtual entities](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/virtual-entities)

You can do the query you want via query builder (or execute a raw SQL directly), and get the result as POJO via `qb.execute()`:

```js
const res = await em.createQueryBuilder(User, 'u')
  .select(['u.id', 'u.username', 'count(p.id) as count'])
  .leftJoin('u.posts', 'p')
  .groupBy('u.id')
  .execute();
```

Or as the `User` entity via `qb.getResult()`. For this approach you also need to define a non-persistent property to which you can then map the QB result - so in this case `count`.

```js
@Entity()
class User {
  @Property({ persist: false })
  count?: number;
}

const users = await em.createQueryBuilder(User, 'u')
  .select(['u.id', 'u.username', 'count(p.id) as count'])
  .leftJoin('u.posts', 'p')
  .groupBy('u.id')
  .getResult();
```

In v4 you could also use `@Filter()` for this, where you could define a subquery that will give you the count:

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/dev/docs/docs/defining-entities.md#formulas

Comment: This no longer works with mikro-orm v6 which generates query like `\`count(p\`.\`id)\` as \`count\`` for SQLite and throws with `SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: count(p.id)`

Comment: However in v6 there are new [raw sql helpers](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/raw-queries)